# Error using `spring-security-openid` with `spring-integration-core` on classpath

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, openid, spring-integration

I have recently implemented OpenID login using Google on my project. I used [this tutorial](http://krams915.blogspot.se/2011/02/spring-security-3-openid-login-with_13.html?m=1) to get familiar with the library. It wouldn't work in my project, when the login form was submitted a request ended up at my authentication controller, rather than redirecting to Google. After hours of stripping my project down to nothing I found the problem, when I have `spring-integration-core` on the classpath it does not work.

Investigating this problem I downloaded the source for the [example](http://krams915.blogspot.se/2011/02/spring-security-3-openid-login-with_13.html?m=1), adding `spring-integration-core` to the dependency list causes the same problem I was getting. Ideally I would like to use `spring-integration` in my project, and therefore help to get to the bottom of this would be appreciated.

I get the same problem with a combination of `spring-security` `3.0.5` and `3.1.3`, and `spring-integration-core` `2.2.0` and `2.2.3`.

The dependency hierarchy looks ok to me (there are not any obvious conflicting spring versions).
[image: Dependencies]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an <exclusion> for spring-context on the spring-retry dependency.

Comment: Would this have any effect? `spring-context: 3.0.5` would be on the classpath regardless surely? The rest of spring libs are `3.0.5`

Comment: From what I saw above, I assumed the rest would be 3.1.3.

Comment: That version of `spring-integration-core` lists `spring-core` `3.0.3` libraries as dependencies in its POM, that's why they are there. But because I have otherwise specified to use `3.0.5` they have been omitted. I have tried using `spring-core` `3.1.3` libraries with the same result.